# Extract row index from slickgrid using a unique cell value

Tags: slickgrid

```
    rowname="r1";
    changes[1]["num1"] = "changed";
    grid.invalidateRow(1);
    grid.setCellCssStyles("highlight", changes);

    grid.render();
```

Is there a way to get the index of a row in slickgrid if I have a cell value of first column which is unique? In the above code I want to use as changes[rowindex]["num1"]="changed" where "num1" is my column name and "r1" is first column cell value.changes["r1"]["num1"]="changed" does not works.

Comment: I want to know the row index if I have a value="r1" in my grid.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this...

```
for(var i=0; i<grid.getDataLength(); i++){
   if(grid.getData()[i].firstColumnID == 'firstColumnValue'){
       rowIndex = i;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getRowById(id)` - Returns the index of a row with a given id

Comment: It says the slickgrid has no method 'getRowById' ,can u give me a working code?

Comment: seems that your are not using `dataview` it will only work when you will use dataview as follows 'dataView.getRowById()'

Comment: can u explain its complexity too?? I mean does it takes constant time to search the index?

Comment: for more on dataview visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128680/slickgrid-what-is-a-data-view And https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/DataView

Comment: Hey thanx,also I am updating the slickgrid with the help of this: dataView.updateItem(args.item.id, row); But i have a number of rows to update simultaneously.So how can i update array of rows in dataview in slickgrid?

Comment: dataView.setItems(data); This will fire the change events and update the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late but may be with better solution?

`grid.getData().getIdxById('UniqueFieldValue')`