# Slickgrid - Automatic scrolling to current date on page load

Tags: javascript, php, html, slickgrid

I have a slickgrid list where it consists of hundreds of data and I have a column date which consists of date. I ordered it by date desc and I have lot of future dates in it and instead of scrolling down to the current date I need an automatic scrolling of the slickgrid to the current date whenever the page is loaded.

I just want to know how this can be achieved in slickgrid. I didn't find any useful links and so I posted it here.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you will need to write a function that finds first row with current date and returns it's row index. Then you could use something like

```
grid.scrollRowIntoView(rowIndex,doPaging)
```

See documentation here:
https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Slick.Grid#scrollRowIntoView

Answer (score 0):

There's no code here to try and replicate, but here is an approach I can think of.

We can find the date value in the slick grid row [Extract row index from slickgrid using a unique cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189722/extract-row-index-from-slickgrid-using-a-unique-cell-value)  and get the row index, then use slick grid's gotoCell to go to that row.